# Create scratch org with namespace?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, namespace, scratch-org

How do I create a scratch org that has the same namespace as my Developer Edition org where the managed package is held?

I've followed the instructions in the "[Link a Namespace to a Dev Hub Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm)" page to link the namespace to my Dev Hub org, but I cannot find any instructions on any of the documentation pages below for how to actually *create* a new scratch org that has the same namespace as my DE org.

- [Create Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_create.htm)
- [Scratch Org Definition File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm)
- [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the project configuration file, specify the namespace.

```
{ 
"packageDirectories" : [ 
    { "path": "force-app", "default": true}
  ],
"namespace": "myns", 
"sfdcLoginUrl" : "https://login.salesforce.com", 
"sourceApiVersion": "44.0"
}
```

This really only alluded to in the documentation, but `sfdx-project.json` is the key to creating a scratch org with a namespace.

Comment: Also worth noting that the namespace has to be registered in your dev org, otherwise you'll get a cryptic error message about some kind of standard javascript name, IIRC.

Comment: Beautiful. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would totally expect the namespace setting to be in the scratch org definition file, and not the project file. So confusing.

Comment: @sfdxfox- i need to create a scratch org without namespace. Would I then just make namespace field blank?

Comment: @Seyitbek yes, use the empty string (`""`) to denote that there is no namespace.

Comment: Alternatively use the [--nonamespace parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_create.htm) on the force:org:create command line.

Answer (score 1):

[Link a Namespace to a Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.enus.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm)

You should have two developer edition orgs :

- Packaging org   : that contains the managed packages and the namespace
- Development  org :that we use to create the scratch org

Steps:

1. Enable devhub in the development dev org
2. [development dev org] Go to profile (system admin) make sure that "SalesforceDX Namespace Registry" is checked
3. [development dev org] From the app launcher look for "Namespace Registries" list view
4. [development dev org] Click on link namespace and authorize the Packaging org
5. Add namespace attribute to the sfdx-project.json file:

> "namespace": "your_name_space"

6. Create the scratch org

   sfdx force:org:create -s  -a   -f  config/project-scratch-def.json  -d

Comment: I was not able to open the link but this one worked. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm&type=5

Comment: According to the documentation I found, `namespace` is not a valid attribute for the scratch org definition file. I think you might be thinking about `sfdx-project.json`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm